# Spark: Change the Key of key value pair

Tags: python, apache-spark, keyvaluepair

Is it possible to change the key of a key-value pair ? I load from different folders and the key is currently just the path to the file, but I want to change the key into a Integer depending from which folder the file comes.

```
dir_pair_data = sc.wholeTextFiles(mypath)
dir_pair_data = dir_pair_data.map(lambda (x,y) : os.path.dirname(x),y )
```

of course this doesn't work... does anyone have a hint for me, I'm pretty new to spark an python...

Comment: do you care what the integers are, you could use `hash(os.path.dirname(x))`  but there is a risk of collisions.

Comment: Not really but in mypath are currently 3 different folders  and every RDD Pair from folder 1 should have the same key (same for folder 2 and 3). The big problem for me is changing the key to any integer...

Comment: `hash()` will return the same value for the same input, and given your input size very unlikely to create a collision. Alternatively look into `broadcast` variables and create a dictionary lookup.

Comment: Sounds good. But how can I manipulate a Key ? my attempt with .map doesn't work and I can't find a function which lets me map the keys. maybe I'm just blind....

Comment: Just bracket your tuple, `(os.path.dirname(x), y)`, the ',' is interpreted as an argument list not a tuple in this context.

Comment: oh Thank you sooo much now it works! I'm a Python Noob :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following piece of code accomplishes what you want in terms of keying each set of files by a unique ID corresponding to its parent directory (though admittedly, it could be optimized since I'm a little new to pyspark myself):

```
dir_pair_data = sc.wholeTextFiles(mypath)
dir_pair_data = (dir_pair_data
                 .map(lambda (x,y): (os.path.dirname(x), y))
                 .groupByKey()
                 .values()
                 .zipWithUniqueId()
                 .map(lambda x:(x[1], x[0]))
                 .flatMapValues(lambda x: x))
```

As a summary of the steps:

1. **map** -- places the key-value pairs into tuples, converting the key into the parent directory
2. **groupByKey** -- groups all text files by the corresponding parent directory
3. **values** -- sheds the parent directory element and returns only the grouped text files
4. **zipWithUniqueId** -- provides a unique `Long` identifier to each grouped set of text files
5. **map** -- swaps elements so the key is the `Long` id
6. **flatMapValues** -- flattens the grouped text files so that each file is contained within its own own record

Comment: Thank you, works great, got my own solution aswell which is kinda clunky :D

data_pared = dir_pair_data.map(lambda (x,y) : ((abs(hash(os.path.dirname(x).split("/")[-1])))%(10 ** 10),y) )